# Way to disable Fiddler or Debuggers without complicated routs or user agent treatment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis, web

Has any one figured out ways to secure the data or requests that are visible through fiddler especially (possibly confuse it i know it reads pretty accurate).

Just asking in terms of security i wonder if its possible to hide items as much as possible from public view. I have seen ways to hide the web debuggers but fiddler being such a smarty you can break that with it as well for example go to Facebook and hit the dev tools (f12).

This is related to server side code like c#/vb/net obiously on IIS server and any suggestions or ideas hey even practices would be great

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Describe a precise scenario what data could be extracted using a proxy like Fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

That's why we have HTTPS, all the headers are encrypted during the transportantion of the http package.